# What pattern for deeply nested web form validation?

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications, validation

I'm refactoring a large legacy web application that has some complicated forms.

These forms use javascript to display or hide fields on the basis of other entered fields. E.g ticking a checkbox for "second address" reveals a set of other fields to enter.

The current validation for this consists of lots of deeply nested if statements. Similar to:

```
if(checkboxTicked) {
  haveMandatoryAddressFieldsBeenEntered();
   if(addressHasbeenFilledIn) {
        validateAddress()
   }
}
```

Now imagine this example with much deeper nesting!

My question is - is there a nice pattern or best practice that I can refactor this with?

For reference I'm using Spring MVC - but I guess this would apply across multiple technologies.

Answer (score 1):

When using MVC, I put my validation in my model. The model and controller don't know about how the form in the view looks like.